# Best format for user to upload list of email addresses

Tags: php, excel, csv, user-input

I'm building a web app and part of the spec is the ability to create users in bulk by uploading a list of email addresses. I've been weighing a few different options and was hoping to get some input from people with past experience:

I could have them create a spreadsheet and save it as a csv, but I am worried that the users (who are not technically inclined) will mess it up.
I could tell them to just create a list separated by commas, but that would require them to do it by hand.
I could have them upload a spreadsheet and try to parse excel files, but from what I have seen, that is difficult.

Does anyone have experience with this, particularly with what formats are easy to parse in PHP & least likely to cause issues for non technical users?

*edit* To be clear, this is a simple list of email addresses, nothing more.

Comment: Why not a newline-delimited list?

Comment: Because I don't know anyone who stores their data in that format, and I don't want my user to have to manually create the file - though yes, that would be simplest for me

Comment: The answer you accepted *is* a newline-delimited list.

Comment: Yes, because the explanation provided by Marc B illustrated that A newline delimited list satisfied all my requirements. I just didn't realize that at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is it just email addresses? can't get simpler than "one email address per line in a text file". if it's more than just emails, then csv. "enter the data into Excel, file->save as csv"

Comment: Yeah, just emails. I feel like if I say i email per line a text file, the user would have to make that manually.

Comment: you can still use excel - a single column csv will look exactly the same as "one email per line".

Answer (score 2):

[CSV - Comma Separated Values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) if you will also include names with the email address

It's easy to make in Excel or a text editor and PHP handles them easily using [`fgetcsv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

Answer (score 2):

a better approach would be for your app to be able to deal with multiple formats: 1 email per line, comma separated emails, email address + name, etc., and any combinations of the above.  Put more intelligence into your code and you won't have to rely on the (non-technical) user to get things exactly right.